# How to do single line animation in last step (D) custom wizard using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a wizard which is working fine. However when I click on the last button, `D`, then it is not animated as single line. It is working like multi steps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pPtn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').prevAll().addClass('act')
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('act');
  });
});
```

```css
.w-steps {
  width: 1170px;
}

.w-steps ul li {
  height: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.w-steps ul li::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  background: blue;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.45s;
}

.w-steps ul li.act::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.w-steps ul li span.pPtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w-steps">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="pPtn">A</span></li>
    <li><span class="pPtn">B</span></li>
    <li><span class="pPtn">C</span></li>
    <li><span class="pPtn">D</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you animate all the elements at the same time. Instead you need to stagger them based on their index and the amount of time the animation takes to run. This can be done with a `setTimeout()` call in a loop. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pPtn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('li').prevAll().addBack().each(function(i) {
      var $li = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $li.addClass('act');
      }, i * 450);
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.w-steps {
  width: 1170px;
}

.w-steps ul li {
  height: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.w-steps ul li::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  background: blue;
  width: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.45s;
}

.w-steps ul li.act::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.w-steps ul li span.pPtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w-steps">
  <ul>
    <li><span class="pPtn">A</span></li>
    <li><span class="pPtn">B</span></li>
    <li><span class="pPtn">C</span></li>
    <li><span class="pPtn">D</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I reduced the `li` width purely so it fit better in to the snippet. The JS logic will work for any width `li`.

Comment: Thank you @Rory McCrossan it is working fine exactly what i need